# Setting DataGrid StringFormat in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have the following datagrid column in XAML for my date. I need to format it in "MM/dd/yyyy" format.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" Header="Date" />
```

How do I reproduce the string formatting part in C#? I want to add new columns to my Datagrid in code.

```
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
textColumn.Header = "Date";
textColumn.Binding = new Binding("MyDate");
textColumn.CanUserReorder = true;
//????
this.MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var binding = new Binding("MyDate");

binding.StringFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
textColumn.Binding = binding;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
 textColumn.Binding = new Binding("MyDate") {StringFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"};
```